# Switching to Tablet support and Fragment using template SettingsActivity from Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android

I generated the below code from the default template SettingsActivity from Eclipse and ADT. I find it overly complicated. I also added some pieces myself. How can I improve the structure?

1. Currently Activity listener and a Fragment listener -> Better way?
2. Get rid of the static Preference proxyEmail = null; -> How? Is static OK?
3. How can I call/use findPreference(getText(R.string.key_proxy_email)) in onPreferenceChange() method (line 123)?
4. Refactor ideas?

   ```
   package com.xyz.abc;

   import java.util.List;

   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
   import android.content.res.Configuration;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
   import android.preference.ListPreference;
   import android.preference.Preference;
   import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
   import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
   import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
   import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

       private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

       @Override
       protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setupSimplePreferencesScreen();

           // TODO Not used at the moment
           //final SharedPreferences sp = new SecureSharedPreferences(this, this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) );

           SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Global.PREFERENCES, 0);
           boolean sent = settings.getBoolean(Global.PREF_SETTING_SENT, false);
           if (sent) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Global.TOAST_MSG_SENT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Global.TOAST_MSG_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           }

       }

       private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
           if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
               return;
           }

           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_dummy);   // Be able to display first title
           PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);       
           fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_settings);     
           getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);

           fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);  
           fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_advanced);
           getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_advanced);

           fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);  
           fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_general);
           getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

           SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
           sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

           toggleProxyEmail(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_via)), findPreference(getText(R.string.key_proxy_email)));
       }

       /** {@inheritDoc} */
       @Override
       public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
           return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
       }

       /**
        * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
        */
       private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
           return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
       }

       private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
           return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB || !isXLargeTablet(context);
       }

       /** {@inheritDoc} */
       @Override
       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
       public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
           if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
               loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
           }
       }

       private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener bindPrefSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
               String stringValue = value.toString();

               if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                   // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in the preference's 'entries' list.
                   ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                   int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                   // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                   preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index] : null);

               } else {
                   // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
                   preference.setSummary(stringValue);
               }
               return true;
           } 

       };

       private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener bindPrefKeyToEditTextListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {    
               ((CheckBoxPreference) preference).setChecked((Boolean) value);
               toggleProxyEmail(preference, SettingsPreferenceFragment.proxyEmail);

               return true;
           }

       };

       private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
           preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(bindPrefSummaryToValueListener);

           // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's current value.
           bindPrefSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
       }

       private static void bindPreferenceKeyToEditText(Preference preference) {
           preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(bindPrefKeyToEditTextListener);

           // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's current value.
           bindPrefKeyToEditTextListener.onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getBoolean(preference.getKey(), false));
       } 


       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
       public static class SettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

           static Preference proxyEmail = null;

           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);

               proxyEmail = findPreference(getText(R.string.key_proxy_email));
               toggleProxyEmail(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_via)), proxyEmail);

               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_dest_email)));
               bindPreferenceKeyToEditText(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_via)));
               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_proxy_email)));
               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_pwd)));
               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_provider)));
           } 
       }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
       public static class AdvancedPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_advanced);
           }
       }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
       public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_help)));
           }
       }

       private static void toggleProxyEmail(Preference prefKey, Preference prefValue) {
           if (prefKey instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
               if(((CheckBoxPreference) prefKey).isChecked()) {
                   prefValue.setEnabled(true);
               } else {
                   prefValue.setEnabled(false);
               }
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {    // Only called in a normal Activity
           if(key.equals(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_via)).getKey())) {
               toggleProxyEmail(findPreference(getText(R.string.key_via)), findPreference(getText(R.string.key_proxy_email)));
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: define "overly complicated".

Comment: It's not really overly complicated, it's just that this Class does two things (depending on the SDK version). Keep shared methods static like the ADT plugin does for the listeners.

Comment: @A--C How would you improve the call to toggleProxyEmail()? And my other points, any idea? Any why do you say "Keep shared methods static", could you elaborate please...

Comment: @wtsang02 Basically I like to improve the two first points and then get input on how I can refactor it better. Especially toggleProxyEmail() method.

Comment: @powder366 I say keep them static so they don't depend on an instance of the object, since these methods are usually just listener bindings. Also, if you find that this is merge is too much, you are always welcome to create two separate Activities, one for >=3.0 and < 3.0.